# Ecologically Correct Troglodyte

Tags: creature-design, fantasy-races, ecology

The troglodyte is a strange humanoid creature found in histories from Rome and Ancient Greece

They live in caves (as the name implies), and do not use much technology. They do have a language, which sounds like bat screeches. They are obligate carnivores, and subsist mostly on raw reptile flesh. They are also very quick runners. They are said to dwell near the Horn of Africa

Is there any niche that this unique race could fit into?

Comment: how's your world going?

Comment: quick runner and cave dwelling are not things that will occur together. you may have ot ditch cave dwelling for denning in caves and spend the rest of their time outside. No animal similar o a human is going to survive as a cave dwelling species, there just is not enough calories available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Giant Cat

The troglodytes have a lifestyle similar to that of cats. Specifically, they would be ambush predators that conceal themselves and wait for (or perhaps even lure in) a fat lizard or snake to eat. They then swiftly reach and grab it tightly, and then eat their prize

## Why Reptiles?

Perhaps reptiles are simply more abundant/available in the world troglodytes inhabit, which inevitably leads to them being eaten more. Snakes specifically often have venom, which isn't so appetizing to most creatures, so these troglodytes could also have a level of venom resistance to clear up the snakes

## Speed

Being fast is a good way to avoid predators. While stealth is a good first resort, speed will still help if found out. Their speed will also help them catch their prey

## Bats and Caves

Caves are relatively safe places to sleep, if you can't make a house. And if they use lures, it would be a good place to hunt; the lack of light would make the wandering reptiles much less likely to spot the hunter. Their cave-dwelling nature also explains their voice. Echolocation is a useful way to navigate in darkness, as in caves or nighttime. It would also be a good way to look for prey without alerting them, as most common reptiles have rather poor hearing

Answer (score 4):

**They are Dahalo people.**

The KhoiSan ethnic group was once dispersed across Africa.  There are still populations who are phenotypically Khoisan in Kenya and Somalia.  There were undoubtedly more in classical times.  The Dahalo were hunter gatherers and so might have eaten snakes.  Their language had (has?) sounds that would have been unfamiliar to classical authors and so described as sounding like birds.

https://www.govisitkenya.com/daharo-people.html

> Dahalo has a highly diverse sound system using all four airstream
> mechanisms found in human language: clicks, ejectives, and implosives,
> as well as the universal pulmonic sounds.
>
> It is suspected that the Dahalo may have once spoken a Sandawe- or
> Hadza-like language, and that they retained clicks in some words.
>
> They are often referred as the remnants of Africa's oldest cultural
> group the san.

Answer (score 0):

**Cave Wall Salamander**

[image]

What you have here is a species of long cave salamander. Similar to the Olm above but larger and with longer front legs. They are ambush predators that climb up the cave wall, until their head is at the same height as a human. They wait for something to wander into the cave and then pounce on it with their strong front legs.

Usually that something is a lizard that comes into the cave at night. During the night the caves are warmer than the surrounding area, either due to geothermal activity, or simply because the deep stone retains heat from the day.

The lizard is uncooked because lizards don't know how to cook themselves. They don't have the technology you see.

Humans who encounter them in the darkness often mistake them for upright creatures, rather than creatures clinging to the wall. In other words they mistake this:

[image]

for this:

[image]

In their defense it is VERY dark in those caves.

When the salamander screes and drops to the floor out of sight, the human mistakenly thinks the upright creature ran away quickly.